# A Syntax Question: Validating Meta Keys with Capital letters?

Tags: html, validation, syntax, seo, capitalization

Dear folks, somewhere on the net I read a person advising:

*`" Validate your meta keys dude. Validating it would help (Mostly, make all letters CAPITAL and add / before the ending >  "`*

What does that mean? does that mean

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?=$canonical?>">
```

should be

```
<LINK REL="CANONICAL" HREF="<?=$canonical?>"/>
```

?? Thanks for clarification

Comment: Adding slash when there is no closing tag (<link .../>, <br/> etc.) makes it xhtml compliant (or does not, but missing / makes it non-compliant). Tag case (LINK/link) do not matter.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Whoever wrote it didn't know what he was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he talked only about attribute names.. ie.

```
<LINK REL="canonical" HREF="<?=$canonical?>" />
```

But **case doesn't matter afaik**. Ad. validation: He was probably talking about w3c html validator.